# Writing a setter for current path

Tags: java, path

I would like to write getter and setter for current path.

```
private Path currentPath;
public Path getCurrentPath() {
    currentPath = Paths.get(".").toAbsolutePath().normalize();
    return currentPath;
}

@Override
public void setCurrentPath(Path p) {
     currentPath = Paths.get(".").toAbsolutePath().normalize();
}
```

It looks like that getter works fine, but setter not.
Can someone help me?

Comment: Because you are not using argument `p` which is of `path` type.

Comment: just do `p.toAbsolutePath().normalize();`

Comment: Also, you have to make sure that once your setter sets `currentPath`, that your class gives you a way to get it.  Right now, your getter will throw away whatever's in `currentPath` and set it to something else.  So that makes your setter useless, unless there's some other method in your class that uses `currentPath`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't using parameter `p` passed in to your setter method. To use it, yoou need to do something like:

```
@Override
public void setCurrentPath(Path p) {
     currentPath = p.toAbsolutePath().normalize();
}
```

Also getter shouldn't be changing the value of currentPath (i.e. it should return whatever the value of `currentPath` is)

Comment: Is this getter ok? return Paths.get(".").toAbsolutePath().normalize();

Comment: No. Your getter should be idempotent i.e. should not cause any sideeffect to your currentPath. So it should be as simple as `public Path getCurrentPath() {return currentPath;}`

Comment: Can you tell me how to solve problem - getter always returns same

Comment: Yes it would as i said. Unless you reset the value using setter method, you are going to get the same value and that's how it should be.

Comment: Can we talk in chat?